# GNOME control center reports GNOME version 3.36.3 while screenfetch reports 3.36.4

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 and the settings says that I have GNOME 3.36.3 but screenfetch says that I have GNOME 3.36.4.

Which version do I have then?

Comment: `gnome-shell --version` output plz..

Comment: This is a reproducible issue since `gnome-shell --version` also reports 3.36.4. So, it seems like a bug.

Comment: ........ yeah ......................  thanks.